# How to get React to update component and run function on component update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple stock ticker app. Type in a symbol like AAPL, TSLA, GOOG and show the current price of all 3.

The problem is, after the first stock entered, I can't get the component to auto-update. It only updates on an interval (15 seconds via setInterval).

How do I get my component to update on form submit? In `StockList` I have props that contain the symbol names passed down from my main `App` component. I pass them down to `StockInfo` via props again, where I run `getStock()` for my API call to get prices. This works fine the first passthrough, but anytime I enter more stocks the component does not update unless `setInterval` runs. I'm running `this.setState` in `StockInfo`, but it doesn't seem to matter.

What am I missing?

```
class StockList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <StockInfo stocks={this.props.symbols} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

//

```
class StockInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      symbols: [], 
      text: '', 
      stock: [], 
      time: new Date().toLocaleString() 
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
      return {
        symbols: props.stocks,
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(
      //interval
      () => {this.getStocks()},
      10 * 1000
    );

    this.getStocks();
    console.log("mounting StockInfo")
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      time: new Date().toLocaleString()
    });
  }

  getStocks() {
    this.tick();

    var symbol_str = "";
    var stock_list = [];
    if (this.state.symbols.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.symbols.length; i++) {
        stock_list.push(this.state.symbols[i].text);
      }
    }

    this.setState({symbols: stock_list});
    symbol_str = stock_list.join();

    //stock api call here

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <b>The time is {this.state.time}.</b>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.stock.map((obj, index) =>
              // Only do this if symbols have no stable IDs
              <li key={index}>
                <span className="stock_name">{obj.quote.symbol}</span> - <span className="stock_latest_price">{obj.quote.latestPrice}</span>
              </li>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For updating state on every component update, you can use the **getDerivedStateFromProps** lifecycle (if react version > 16), else the **componentDidUpdate** lifecycle can be used.

Refer the link [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: I tried putting getDerivedStateFromProps in the StockInfo component, and even updating the state every single props change, but it does not work as intended. I figured it would update the StockInfo on every form submit, but instead if still waits for the 15 second interval.

Comment: Can you update the post with ur code in getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Updated StockInfo with getDerivedStateFromProps(). It will update on first stock input, and 2nd stock input will only update when setInterval is called, never on form submit. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you use the latest version of React, you may need to observe the changes of the props.
Check the documentation of the    **getDerivedStateFromProps**    method

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

previously used     **componentWillReceiveProps()**, but it was considered insecure and will be marked as deprecated in upcoming updates

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You need to setState the stock on the form input as well:

```
<form>
  <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({stock: e.target.value})}/>
</form>
```

Once you setState on input change it will re-render/update your component.

Comment: The form works fine. I can pass items to the StockList just fine onchange and onsubmit. It's from StockList to StockInfo that's the problem.

Comment: Then you should look into new react new life cycle method getDerivedStateFromProps (provided you are using latest version of React) or componentWillRecieveProps (in case of older version of React)